# Can’t import TA-Lib on Mac (Python)

Tags: python, macos, ta-lib

I’m using Python 3.7 on MacOs 10.12.6. I’ve been trying to install talib in every way possible and I still get “no module named talib” when I try to import it in Python. I’m on Google page 10 looking for solutions, tried with brew, pip3, downloading the python wrapper from github… was anybody able to make this work?

If it’s useful info, I don’t have Cython installed, should I? I don’t use that normally

I saw somebody trying this, but it was a fix for a different problem, it was for Windows, and it used binary, which is not available for Mac:

```
$ tar -xvf ta-lib-0.4.0-src.tar.gz 
$ cd ta-lib
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```